# Why is the 1 in this index + 1 showing up in my directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a directive with an `$index`:

**HTML:**

```
<tr
     reportrowgroup
     ng-repeat="report in reports | orderBy: sortBy track by $index"
     report="report"
     rowindex="{{$index + 1}}"
```

**JS:**

```
'<td>{{rowindex + 1}}</td>'+

scope: {
  report: '=',
  rowindex: "@"
```

It works but the result looks like this:

```
11
21
31
```

It seems like the 1 is being added in `rowindex + 1`. How to output the usual 1, 2, 3, etc?

Comment: try changing the @ to an &

Comment: From the ng docs about '@': The result is always a string since DOM attributes are strings. About '&':  provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the correct value to directive using rowindex="{{$index + 1}}". The problem is inside the directive, you should use '{{rowindex}}'. I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like $index is being interpreted as a string. Try this instead:

```
rowindex="{{ Number($index) + 1 }}"
```

Comment: after making that change, I get 11, 11, 11, haha.

Answer (score 0):

You can do subtraction instead :)

```
rowindex="{{ $index - -1 }}"
```

or

```
"{{($index-0) + 1}}"
```

Comment: It's not really clear how this would solve the problem.

Comment: subtraction will force the string to be converted to a number. A simple test will show you, put `"3" - -1` in your console.